# Parts of the object do not move in Object Mode

Tags: object-mode

I am trying to model a 3D snake in Blender with a simple, goofy animation.
I edited some vertices in the snake head object after I set the animation. Now when I try to move the snake head in object mode, those vertices do not move. I don't know what is causing this. I will link a file because I don't feel I can explain the problem properly.

Link to the file: https://we.tl/t-7Pysae76B4

Answer (score 2):

You've hooked the head as well, remove these *Hook* modifiers or at least disable them:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem.